# Handle webservice objects in php?

Tags: php, soap-client

I have an function in a C# webservice that send an array with information.. if I use `var_dump` i get this:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["HamtaAllPersonalResult"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["AllPersonal"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (8) { ["AdressPersonal"]=> string(13) "Skuttgatan 11" ["EfternamnPersonal"]=> NULL ["FornamnPersonal"]=> string(4) "Kurt" ["HemtelefonPersonal"]=> string(8) "05201234" ["MailPersonal"]=> string(14) "Perra@berra.se" ["MobiltelefonPersonal"]=> string(9) "070123456" ["PnrPersonal"]=> string(10) "8012135050" ["PostnrPersonal"]=> string(5) "12345" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (8) { ["AdressPersonal"]=> string(10) "Ankgatan 1" ["EfternamnPersonal"]=> NULL ["FornamnPersonal"]=> string(5) "Kalle" ["HemtelefonPersonal"]=> string(8) "05671234" ["MailPersonal"]=> string(13) "Kalle@anka.se" ["MobiltelefonPersonal"]=> string(9) "070239348" ["PnrPersonal"]=> string(10) "7812085790" ["PostnrPersonal"]=> string(5) "56431" } } } }
```

How can you use the data to put it in for example a gridview... in other words how can i collect only the useful information, for exampel "Skuttgatan 11"...??

i use this code to get data but it only work if i send one object from the webservice:

```
$soap_client = new
soapclient("http://tsb01.cnap.hv.se/PersonalService/ServicePersonal.svc?wsdl");      
$quote2 = $soap_client->HamtaAllPersonal();
var_dump($quote2);
foreach($quote2 as $record)
{
    echo $record->AllPersonal->AdressPersonal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're simply iterating over the wrong thing. Try this:

```
foreach ($quote2->HamtaAllPersonalResult->AllPersonal as $person) {
    echo $person->AdressPersonal;
}
```

At the moment, you're iterating over a `stdClass` object. I assume you actually want to loop over its `AllPersonal` member, which is a two-element array.